# static libraries in Xcode 5 with workspaces

Tags: ios, xcode

Is anyone having problems with static libraries with workspaces.  I was looking at an old workspace where I had one normal xcode project, and one static library.  It was working fine in Xcode 5.  Then I wanted to add a new static lib I was working on.  I added the header file in the viewcontroller I wanted to try to use it, added the static lib to my workspace, and added my static lib as one of the frameworks to link against.

```
#import "CTAutoLayoutUtilities/CTAutoLayoutUtilities.h"
```

It built fine with just the header file in place.  I started typing and I saw that my static library that has some categories in it appear in the intellisense.  Then I tried building, and I got an error saying that it cannot find the header file listed above.  I did not change the User Header Search Paths from before when my static library was working.  It still has:

```
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)
```

After that, I tried the cleaning of the project (cmd + shift + option + k).  Then rebuilt, and now it's complaining that it cannot find the header files for either of my static libraries, including the one that originally worked up until now.  I then removed the new static lib from the frameworks to link against, but the compiler still complains it cannot find the header file original static library that worked.

Does anyone know if something got changed in Xcode 5 or how I can get my libraries to be recognized again?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use an Xcode Workspace all the time and haven't noticed any changes from Xcode 4 WRT include paths.

I always do the following:

- Put all projects in my `~/Source` folder so they are all at the same level (i.e. they are all siblings).
- Create an Xcode project and test it before adding it to the Xcode Workspace.
- I always manually set the `Header Search Path` in the project settings for any project that uses another project; for example:

  ```
  $(PROJECT_DIR)/../OtherProject1/include
  $(PROJECT_DIR)/../OtherProject2/include
  /opt/local/include
  ```
- I never have to set `Library Search Path` as the binaries/libraries are always put into the same directory in the `DerivedData` folder.